# How to get text from preg_match()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$text = "About 5,590 results";

preg_match("/of about <b>(.*?)</", $text, $matches);
```

it return the 5590 but when I tried with :

```
$text = "4 results";
preg_match("/of about <b>(.*?)</", $text, $matches);
```

is there any pattern for this case? I want to get "4" from "4 results"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need the numbers, you can use this regex:

```
$regex = "/\d+[\.,]?\d*/";
```

This will match numbers in the following formats:

- 5
- 5.590
- 5,590
- 5590